# Normally distributed points within a square in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, normal-distribution

How can I create N normally distributed points within a N x N square with the mean at the centre (More points concentrated at the centre). I would appreciate an approach in which the coordinates of each points could be stored in a struct. I have tried the code below

```
 for i=1:200
 S(i).x=randn*200;
 S(i).y=randn*200;
 plot(S(i).x,S(i).y,'.');
 axis([0 200 0 200]); 
 end
```

However, I observed I got negative values. Using a centre [mean] of (100,100) in a square, I want to store normally distributed points between 0-200 for a 200x200 square. Thanks

Comment: Your example generates samples from an uncorrelated normal distribution on the plane. You can use the multi-variable normal distribution function `mvnrnd` to properly specify both the mean and variance of your distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would require the Statistics Toolbox in MATLAB. You can create a truncated normal distribution, which by definition would only generate normally distributed random numbers within the range `[0, N]`.

```
% Create a normal distribution
N = 200;
pd = makedist('Normal', 'mu', N/2, 'sigma', 60)

% Truncate the normal distribution to [0,N]
t = truncate(pd, 0, N)

% Samples from normal distribution
x = pd.random(N,1);
y = pd.random(N,1);
subplot(211)
plot(x,y,'bx')
title('Normal Distribution')

% Samples from truncated distribution
x = t.random(N,1);
y = t.random(N,1);
subplot(212)
plot(x,y,'ro')
title('Truncated Normal Distribution')
```

This would result in something like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should use `rand` to generate *uniformly* distributed points.
 `randn` is used for **normally** distributed points and this is why you get negative values

to center the normally distributed points around 100 you need to add the mean to the result:

```
S(i).x = randn*200 + 100;
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually meant normally distributed points. I just made corrections to the question.

Comment: @Abdulhameed unlike uniform distribution, normal distribution is not bounded and you can have values larger than 200and smaller than zero

Comment: Thanks Shai! Without a bound, the points will not fall into the 200 x 200 dimension. I really appreciate your contribution.